# geodjango distance btw points in two models

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

Firstly i need to say that it is my first GeoDjango task – so if there are some „RTF” lines pls let me know.

I have two Django models:

The facility model. For combination of code1 and code2 can exist few facilityNames in different locations.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField, GeoManager, Model

class Facility(models.Model):
    facilityName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    codeName1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    codeName2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    point = point = PointField()
```

The supervision model. Can have many submissions per facility.
With static methods I can match code1 and code2 and apply proper codeName1 and codeName2.

```
class Supervision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    facilityName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    codeName1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    codeName2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    point = models.PointFiled()

    @staticmethod
    def update_codeName1():
        for r in Facility.objects.all():
            Supervision.objects.filter(code1=r.code1).update(codeName1=r.codeName1)

    @staticmethod
    def update_codeName2():
        for r in Facility.objects.all():
            Supervision.objects.filter(code2=r.code2).update(codeName2=r.codeName2)
```

Main task is to match and update facilityName in Supervision model with facilityName from Facility model as another staticmethod.

This should be lookup on code1, code2 and point with smaller distance btw facility point and supervision point.

Any tips, directions etc. most appreciated.

Thanks,

J

UPDATE 1:
Im tryin something like that but Im not sure about the results yet:

```
@staticmethod
for r in Supervision.objects.filter(code1Name='Default'):
    pnt = r.point
    Facility.objects.filter(code1=r.code1, code2=r.code2,point__distance_lte=(pnt,0.2))
```

UPDATE 2:

Have some progress but still need to take minimal distance from result of distance() which is float ghzzz or try to switch to meters maybe...

```
from app.models import Supervision, Facility
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
def distance():
    for r in Supervision.objects.filter(lganame='Defaul'):
        pnt_01 = GEOSGeometry(r.point.wkt, srid=4326)
        print str(pnt_01)+' SS in '+r.hf_name
        rs = Facility.objects.filter(code1=r.code1, code2=r.code2)
        for x in rs:
            pnt_02 = GEOSGeometry(x.point.wkt, srid=4326)
            print str(pnt_02)+' Facility: '+x.name+' : '+str(pnt_01.distance(pnt_02)*100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time for answer then:

```
def text1():
for r in Supervision.objects.all():
    try:
        x = Facility.objects.filter(code1=r.code1, code2=r.code2).distance(r.point).order_by('distance')[:1].get()

        r.facilityName = x.facilityName
        r.save()
        print x.primary_name
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print 'Does Not Exist!'
        pass
```